# IntelliJ IDEA 14 build project okay but shows a lot of errors in editor

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide

I am encountered a strange error of IntelliJ IDEA today. The project rebuild is all good and I can run the unit test cases, however when I open the source files it displays a lot of errors all due to "Cannot resolve symbols". It looks like the editor doesn't recognize the class files it built:

[image]

Comment: Are your dependencies correct? Are you using any sort of code-generation?

Answer (score 1):

This is typically occurs when the indexes IDEA uses have become corrupt. Thus IDEA cannot properly resolve things. Go to `File > Invalidate Caches`. Invalidate the caches and restart IDEA. Let it re-index the project (progress will show right of the center of the bottom status bar). Once the indexing is completed, the invalid error marks should go away.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest deleting the .idea folder then open the project again.

This worked for me.